# 0.5 steps doesn't function in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, diagrams

I have a diagram that should show the changes in 0.5 steps, but somehow it seems that there are only 1 steps.[image]

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            width=\textwidth,
            height=15cm,
            xlabel={$Taktzahl$},
            ylabel={$Tempo~in~bpm$},
            ymin=0, ymax=150,
            ymin=0, ymax=140,
            ]
            \addplot[black] table{Daten/5Sht.txt};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Tempodiagramm}
\end{figure}


116 101.333 40.4
116,5   99.1457 1.3
117 113.895 41.1
117,5   61.7993 1.4
118 83.5227 41.2
118,5   108.514 2.1
119 113.895 41.3
119,5   102.845 2.2
120 118.729 41.4
120,5   120.966 2.3
121 128.797 42.1
121,5   121.958 2.4
122 106.01  42.2
122,5   99.1457 3.1
123 36.555  42.3
123,5   36.9471 3.3
124 51.9567 42.4
124,5   53.4664 3.4
125 47.686  43.1
125,5   61.7993 4.1
126 57.4219 43.2
126,5   63.8021 4.2
127 59.1311 43.3
127,5   63.8205 4.3
128 66.5761 43.4
128,5   55.5696 4.4
129 56.9473 44.1
129,5   65.314  5.1
130 62.0777 44.2
130,5   63.8021 5.2
131 59.147  44.3
131,5   42.9322 5.3
132 19.6035 44.4
132,5   36.8483 5.4
```

Comment: Please always provide compilable code, in the form of a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). Not only does it make things easier for the people willing to help you, but it's also necessary to see  the context.

Comment: `116,5` should be `116.5` I assume.

Comment: You can accept my answer to show that your question is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I assume that you ignored the error messages.
- **You mix comma and dot as the decimal separator.**
- Below you find an example in which I replaced commas with dots.
- In addition, don't put the `label` and `ylabel` in math mode (`$`) if it is just text.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{data.txt}
116 101.333 40.4
116.5   99.1457 1.3
117 113.895 41.1
117.5   61.7993 1.4
118 83.5227 41.2
118.5   108.514 2.1
119 113.895 41.3
119.5   102.845 2.2
120 118.729 41.4
120.5   120.966 2.3
121 128.797 42.1
121.5   121.958 2.4
122 106.01  42.2
122.5   99.1457 3.1
123 36.555  42.3
123.5   36.9471 3.3
124 51.9567 42.4
124.5   53.4664 3.4
125 47.686  43.1
125.5   61.7993 4.1
126 57.4219 43.2
126.5   63.8021 4.2
127 59.1311 43.3
127.5   63.8205 4.3
128 66.5761 43.4
128.5   55.5696 4.4
129 56.9473 44.1
129.5   65.314  5.1
130 62.0777 44.2
130.5   63.8021 5.2
131 59.147  44.3
131.5   42.9322 5.3
132 19.6035 44.4
132.5   36.8483 5.4
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            width = 100mm,
            height = 150mm,
            xlabel = {Taktzahl},
            ylabel = {Tempo in bpm},
            ymin = 0, 
            ymax = 150,
            ymin = 0, 
            ymax = 140,
            ]
            \addplot[black] table {data.txt};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The solution worked just fine. Thank you!